# why does pandas's to_sql create duplicates?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to insert a DB but it keeps creating duplicates, I'm implying doing this:

```
df.to_sql('my_table', schema='my_schema', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, method='multi')
```

I ran it once and I got 10 entires, then reran the script and now it's 20. Is there a way to set this so it doesn't create duplicates but only adds new entries?

Comment: you are appending the same values, so that's expected. You could create a constraint on the db table to avoid duplicates

Comment: @sammywemmy but if I have 10 items in my DB and my new dataframe has 11 items with 1 being new. Would it ignore the 10 and insert the 1 so my DB would have 11 items?

Comment: you are using if_exists= append, which means it will add again if a table exists. if you want to drop the table and create again, try replace  `if_exists= ‘replace’`

Comment: if_exists checks the table existence, not the contents. for the constraint, you could probably write an update statement to cover that. not sure pandas can cover in that regards. the way I think pandas can possibly do it is to add code that checks if your data is already existing in the table (like a set difference) and add just what is new; just don't think it is an efficient process, compared to sql's update

Comment: An option is to pull the existing table, drop duplicates with the current dataframe and then write the remaining rows(s). Though this wouldn't be ideal for a large table.